# Trigger error when deleting row

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2, triggers

When attempting to delete a row, I get the following error:

```
record "new" is not assigned yet
DETAIL:  The tuple structure of a not-yet-assigned record is indeterminate.
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function system_factmetrics_log_change_mv_a_iudt() line 3 at IF
```

Here is my function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION system_factmetrics_log_change_mv_a_iudt() RETURNS TRIGGER
SECURITY DEFINER LANGUAGE plpgsql AS '
BEGIN
  IF NEW IS NULL THEN
    -- must be a DELETE, use OLD
    INSERT INTO system_dailystats_mv_pending_updates (date_id, creative_id, mv_updating, triggering_operation)
      VALUES (OLD.date_id, OLD.creative_id, false, TG_OP);
  ELSE
    INSERT INTO system_dailystats_mv_pending_updates (date_id, creative_id, mv_updating, triggering_operation)
      VALUES (NEW.date_id, NEW.creative_id, false, TG_OP);
  END IF;
  RETURN NULL;
END';
```

My trigger:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS system_factmetrics_log_change_mv_it ON system_factmetrics;
CREATE TRIGGER system_factmetrics_log_change_mv_it AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON system_factmetrics
  FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE system_factmetrics_log_change_mv_a_iudt();
```

Shouldn't my `IF NEW IS NULL THEN` conditional handle deletes adequately?  According to [the docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/plpgsql-trigger.html) `NEW` should be `NULL` for `DELETE` triggers.

What am I missing?

The server is running Postgres 9.2.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this would work:

```
    IF (TG_OP = 'DELETE') THEN
        INSERT INTO system_dailystats_mv_pending_updates
            (date_id, creative_id, mv_updating, triggering_operation)
        VALUES (OLD.date_id, OLD.creative_id, false, TG_OP);
    ELSIF (TG_OP = 'UPDATE' or TG_OP = 'INSERT') THEN
        INSERT INTO system_dailystats_mv_pending_updates
            (date_id, creative_id, mv_updating, triggering_operation)
        VALUES (NEW.date_id, NEW.creative_id, false, TG_OP);
    END IF;
    RETURN NULL;
```

I don't think NEW is null in your case, I think it just doesn't exist.  The docs say it is null for statement level triggers, yours is row level.